# Array memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation

This is a ques of one of the coding sites....

Replace "?" with a integer so that output is 4.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[7];
    int b,c,d,a;
    a=4;
    printf("%d",arr[?]);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to figure this out and found the answer to be -4.
Now if I declare one more variable (like int b,c,d,e,a in line 4 of the code) the answer came out to be -5.

Please someone explain how compiler is behaving and the reason for memory allocation (negative indices).

Comment: There is no valid answer to this - you may be able to find a value which gives the desired result, but it will be compiler-sepcific and architecture-specific and will rely on undefined behaviour

Comment: Well you have not initialized `arr` so you never know!

Comment: Whoever asked you this question doesn't know C programming.

Comment: @another.anon.coward:  he doesn't need to.  The value he is looking for is not in the array and he is relying on C's lack of array bound checking to get to `a`.  This is very bad and whoever set the question needs to be shot unless it is part of *Exploiting Bugs 101*.

Answer (score 2):

First, a word of caution: *NEVER* write any code that relies on this kind of behaviour, as it will vary from compiler to compiler.

Edit: Since the first paragraph apparently wasn't clear enough: accessing an array out of bounds is *undefined behavior*, which means that the compiler may produce a program that does anything the compiler chooses. Here, I'm explaining *what the poster's compiler probably has chosen to do*, but it could also be that the result becomes 4 by chance.

Your compiler has apparently chosen to lay out the variables as follows (assuming that the first variable ends up at address 100):

- 100: `a`
- 104: `d`
- 108: `c`
- 112: `b`
- 116: `arr[0]`
- 120: `arr[1]`
- ...
- 140: `arr[6]`

Since `arr` starts at 116 and the size of each of its elements (`int`) is 4 bytes, `arr[-4]` is at 116 + 4 * (-4) = 100, which is where `a` is located.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, the compiler is not guaranteed to give any sane output at all from this code, and the program is allowed to crash & burn. You can't access an array out-of-bounds, simple as that.

Comment: For all that we know, compiler might not have done this also. Maybe there was some random 4 at the memory location arr[-4] and it just clicked here. This is also possible right? But, on the other hand, is it that if the compiler wouldn't have put the variables in the way suggested by you, would there have been any exception? Just curious to know. Thanks

Comment: @Lundin, really? This is undefined behavior? Couldn't have guessed it by reading the other 10 comments stating the same thing! Guy is merely trying to present a case which had the most probability of happening.

Comment: @Lundin: You _can_ do it, as the OP's code shows, and the resulting undefined behaviour is still some kind of behaviour, which likely has an explanation in what the compiler has chosen to do. As skynorth says, I'm just explaining what probably happened.

Answer (score 1):

C does not check for array boundaries. That means that you can use an index that makes that the memory position you are using is not part of the memory allocated for the array.

When you do, you are accessing other positions in memory. In this example, the following 4 positions are reserved for the int variables `b`, `c`, `d` and `a`

So, you get *out of the array* and into the space of the variables.

Anyway, it may be that it depends of compiler/architecture, but I would have expected the right answer to be `11` (the size of the array + 4 variables)

Comment: Oh, and the other comments are true. This is inherently unsafe and the only reason you can do it in C is because it assumes you will not do this and thus the program does not check the values (so it gets a little faster). Never use code like this IRL